# PHP5: Wind degree to name

Tags: php

My current code:

```
public function transform_wind_direction_to_name($winddirection)
{
    $compass = array('N', 'NNE', 'NE', 'ENE', 'E', 'ESE', 'SE', 'SSE', 'S', 'SSW', 'SW', 'WSW', 'W', 'WNW', 'NW', 'NNW');
    $winddirectionname = $compass[round( ($winddirection - 11.25)  / 22.5)];
    return $winddirectionname;
}
```

When the angle is 360 degrees i get this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined offset: 16
```

Comment: At 360 degrees, even php code gets dizzy...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd probably get that error for any that $winddirection that rounds to array index > 16 or rounds to array index -1. To solve the > 360 case, use the modulo operator (%) before accessing the array - `round( ($winddirection % 360)  / 22.5)`

Comment: Apparently none of those upvoters actually did the math. For your equation to work it will need to be `round( ($winddirection % 360 - 11.25) / 22.5)`

Comment: derp. fixed the modulo placement :|

Comment: why did you delete the -11.25?

Comment: @HyperDevil Subtracting 11.25 then rounding doesn't round to the nearest 22.5. As an example, 11.3 degrees is a bit over 1/32 of the way to 360, so it would be `NNE`. However, if you do `round(11.3-11.25)/22.5`, you would get `round(0.05)/22.5` = 0, which corresponds to `N`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should either be using `floor()` instead of `round()`:

```
(360 - 11.25)  / 22.5) == 15.5

round(15.5) == 16

floor(15.5) == 15
```

Or put in a check for:

```
if( $winddirection >= 360 ) { $winddirection = $winddirection % 360; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You array only has 0-15 elements.  Somehow, your function is trying to read the 16th element.  Just have it roll back over to zero at the 360 degree mark.  They mean the same thing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your array contains 16 strings, but since they are counted from 0, the last string has number 15. So when you use 360 as a paramater, function returns $compass[16] and that doesn't exist.